# What potholes are there Using Graphql with RethinkDb?

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb, graphql

As I understand it's possible graphql with rethinkdb. You can use graphql to query really any data set as its just the middleware really. What issues do I need to watch out for in this implementation? Server will be node.js in my case.

Documentation / examples of others doing this seam lacking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using GraphQL together with RethinkDb and don't see any particular problems in using them together compared to an implementation of a rest api or using mongo etc.

Here are two github projects using GraphQL and RethinkDb (the first one is more lightweight):

- [Isomorphic Material Relay Starter Kit](https://github.com/codefoundries/isomorphic-material-relay-starter-kit)
- [meatier](https://github.com/mattkrick/meatier)

Comment: Good to know. Really like the meatier project. Good idea on a roadmap as I'm moving away from meteor currently.